# Xamarin.Forms Prism - Master not dismissing when selecting master page item

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, master-detail

In my Xamarin.Forms Prism app, I have a MasterDetailPage to handle navigation.  The MasterBehavior is set to Popover.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:My.Mobile.Application.Views;assembly=My.Mobile.Application"
              x:Class="My.Mobile.Application.Frame.MainPage"
              MasterBehavior="Popover">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

When the master is visible, if I select the menu item that is already being displayed as the detail item, the master does not automatically dismiss; I have to swipe the master closed if I want to stay on the same page.

I tried manually registering to the ItemSelected event on my master's list view to be able to explicitly set IsPresented = false on the MasterDetailPage, but the event does not fire when selecting the item that is already being displayed:

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
  }

  private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    IsPresented = false;
  }
}
```

This differs from the behavior of the Xamarin.Forms sample Master-Detail app, which closes the master when a selection is made (even if it is the same item that is already being displayed).

Is this something that is being controlled by Prism?

Comment: Use the `ListView.ItemTapped` event, it will fire even in the selected item.

Comment: @Gusman That seems to do it, thanks.  Since the Prism app automatically closes the Master popover when I make a new selection, it would nice if I didn't have to hook up this event just to set IsPresented = false in the case the already-presented detail selection is made.

Comment: Interesting, because Prism does automatically close the Master even if the target is the same as the current detail. https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs#L327

Comment: @BrianLagunas Yes, it appears to do so.  I had the EventToCommand behavior linked to the ItemSelected event instead of the ItemTapped event, so that ended up being the root cause of the behavior that I was observing.